# Laravel: an array has an object and converts it to array after sorting

Tags: php, laravel

As a result of a database query, I have an array with objects and some other aggregated information, so it looks like:

```
$arr = array();

foreach (User::all() as $user) {
    $arr[] = { 
        "user" => $user, 
        "pjor" => pjor($user, ... params),
        "pacu" => pacu($user, ... params),
        ...
    }
}
```

So the idea of this loop is to have a record for each user with data calculated according to some functions and parameters. I can't use the ORM or the Query Builder for doing what the functions do, becaus tehy aggregate data from several sources, and some aren't in the database

So far, the array works, but it gives me "unordered" data, so I wrote another function that uses `usort()` to order the array as I need it, and that works, the only problem is that after sorting, the `User` model gets coverted to an `array` type, and I lose all the ORM access in the view

So I tried something like:

```
foreach ($arr as $a) {
    $a['user'] => new User($a['user']);
}
```

But of course doesn't work, it I do an horrid thing and make this "cast" in the view, it renders an "incomplete" `User` model, for some reason the only attributes preserved are user id and user's email

So which would be the correct way to sort an array by an specific column that includes an object?

#### Edit

This is my sorting function, it is in a livewire component so `$this->sortby` has the column to sort (`pjor`, `pacu` in the example above), `this->asc` is a boolean to indicate if it is ascending or descending

```
usort($this->arr, function ($a, $b) {
  if ($a[$this->sortby] == $b[$this->sortby]) {
    return 0;
  }
  if ($this->desc) {
    return ($a[$this->sortby] > $b[$this->sortby]) ? -1 : 1;
  } else {
    return ($a[$this->sortby] > $b[$this->sortby]) ? -1 : 1;
  }
});
```

Comment: have you tried User::with('relation')->all(); ?

Comment: where? when I "recreate" the object from the array?

Comment: In the foreach loop istead of `(User:all() as.... )`

Comment: Nope... I'll try, but there must be something else, the first time I run the code works (before passing the data to the view)